What should the [hd-wallet] tag mean?
There are several HD wallet proposals. The most common one is BIP32, and a less common one is gmaxwell's proposal. Recently, we've been getting questions about both of them, both tagged with hd-wallet. 

Clarification of BIP32 hierarchical deterministic multisig scripts
How does HD wallet protect its master public key?

This seems confusing.
I propose moving one of them to a new tag.
Thoughts?

I'm thoroughly confused, to be honest. I call it BIP32 because in pybitcointools the function is called bip32_hdm_. I'll read up on Greg's proposal ASAP. (PS. I'm blown away that I can FINALLY use Meta with iOS SE app! Woo!)

Thats what really confused me at first. Also the wiki page for deterministic wallets is making this more complicated. I think they need a better classification.

@abeikverdi You're one of the people this affects; any idea how we should reclassify them?

@WizardOfOzzie The one you're asking about is BIP32. It's just that that's not the only HD wallet proposal. (PS. I know, right?)

I was thinking of splitting it into bip32 and non-bip32-hd-wallet. That wouldn't be elegant, but it would at least be clear.

@NickODell, Pieter Wuille at this video distinguished them by calling non-bip32-hd-wallet as a deterministic type 2 wallet.

I've merged hd-wallet into bip-32-hd-wallets today, but then found this post. Sounds like I might have made a mistake. Will investigate further.

Update: according to a conversation with Pieter, Maxwell's proposal from 2011 introduced the term "deterministic wallets" but only BIP32 introduced hierarchical-deterministic wallets. Hence, anything labeled "HD-wallet" should refer to BIP32.
